# Weird Behavior when eq() is followed by attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I was experimenting with jQuery trying to create a button that fade out all targeted divs one by one and then fade them in again.. I know I can use .each() and loop to accomplish the same thing but as I mentioned I'm trying to  understand this part of jQuery .

this is the code

```
var divCount = $('.box').length;
var counter = 0;
$('.button').click(function() {
    var divAttr = $('.box').eq(counter).attr('class');
    if ( divAttr !== 'hidden' && counter >= 0 && counter <= divCount){
        $('.box').eq(counter).attr('class','hidden');
        $('.box').eq(counter).css('background', 'gray');
        $('.box').eq(counter).css('border', '1px solid black');
        counter++;
    }
```

and here's my problem, it's this line of code:

```
$('.box').eq(counter).attr('class','hidden');
```

if it's active the scripts target the even/2nd divs only. I know I can use .addClass instead, I tried it and works okay. but I'm just trying to understand what is really going on what am I missing?

html, css and js file can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/33bjnjza/1/

Comment: it would be simpler to use `.is()`, `.addClass()`, and method chaining.

Comment: Guys, I'm not trying to solve the problem, as I mentioned I already solved it, I just want to know what is happening

Comment: You are *removing* all the classes on the element and *replacing* it with just `'hidden'`.  Therefore, `$('.box')` now has one less element.

Comment: `.attr('class','whatever')` will remove all other classes applied, you probably want to `.addClass('whatever')` instead

Comment: and so the var counter changes and as result the targeted element. Aha I got it thank you very much. god I love this place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `$('.box').eq(counter).attr('class','hidden');`, you are *modifying* the element.  You are *removing* the `class` attribute on it (and thus *all* of its classes) and replacing it with just one class, `'hidden'`.

So, when you do `$('.box').eq(counter)` on the next line, it will return a *different* element because `$('.box')` now contains one less element.